# Angular form control not updating the UI just the value

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-forms

I have a form like this:

```
this.filterFormGroup= this.formBuilder.group({
      gmt_scope: [''],
      priority: [''],
      region: [''],
      category: [''],
      status: [''],
      original_deadline: [''],
      responsibles: [''],
      pms: [''],
      updated_at: ['']
    });
```

The form is populated through API:

```
<form [formGroup]="filterFormGroup" >
          <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutWrap="wrap" fxLayout="center center"  class="row">
            <div fxFlex.gt-sm="20" fxFlex="100" class="p-10" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
              <!-- <mat-slide-toggle color="primary" stepper="0" formControlName="gmt_scope">GMT SCOPE</mat-slide-toggle> -->
              <mat-form-field>
                <mat-select  placeholder="GMT Scope" stepper="0" formControlName="gmt_scope" >
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let gmt_scope of gmt_scopes" [value]="gmt_scope.value" >
                    {{ gmt_scope.viewValue }}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
            <div fxFlex.gt-sm="20" fxFlex="100" class="p-10" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
              <mat-form-field>
                <mat-select placeholder="Priority" stepper="0" formControlName="priority">
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let priority of projectAttributes.priorities" [value]="priority.id" >
                    {{ priority.description }}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
```

Once is ready I read some queryParams and set some field of the form like these:

```
setFiltersFromParams(params){
    if ('pms' in params){
      this.filterFormGroup.controls.pms.setValue(params.pms.split(","));
      console.log("Setting the following pms:",params.pms.split(",") )
    }
    if ('region' in params){
      this.filterFormGroup.controls['region'].setValue(params.region,{emitEvent: true});
      console.log("Setting the following region:",params.region )
    }

  }
```

If I check the control values they are updated correctly but from the UI I can't see the option selected they are unselected.

Comment: where is your pms input element in the code?

Answer (score 8):

As you said your GUI is not updated the values but the control values in variable is updated This problem is related to **change Detection**.

do one thing inject the `ChangeDetectorRef` service at component level i.e.

define `private ChangeDetectorRef cd`in the constructor of component.

and where you do the updation of controls programatically in custom event function call this function like this `cd.detectChanges()`.

follow this [link](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html) it will helpful.

Answer (score 0):

setTimeOut worked like charm for me!!!

You can try adding control.patchValue('x') or control.setValue('x') inside a setTimeOut method. You can keep delay as 0 also.

setTimeOut sometimes work as synchronizer. Some event may get interrupted by other events so setting time out can help.

```
 setTimeout(() => {
        (this.form.controls['control1'].patchValue('Hello World');
      }, 0);
```